# Can women ask for fictional men in Jannah?

Tags: women, jannah

This might be a bit weird, but I had to ask. Are women allowed to ask for fictional men in Jannah? I saw a previous question of a man asking, and all the responses were saying yes. However Allah created men and women different, and since men are going to get the Hoor al Ayn and women aren’t, I was wondering if us women could ask for the same thing?

Comment: I don't know about Islamic view, but I don't see any reason why that should not be. The problem definitely starts getting violent when calling for *real* people, especially if they are still alive.

Answer (score 0):

There is no definitive answer to this available to us.

You'll find out once you get there, if you get there.